# Apcelerator ios Build Failed issue

Tags: ios, titanium, google-plus, appcelerator

I have iOS app which is working fine if I run it without adding [gplus](https://github.com/hansemannn/titanium-google-signin) module. As soon as I add it in my project it gives below error.

> [ERROR] :  ** BUILD FAILED **
>   [ERROR] :  The following build commands failed:
>   [ERROR] :     Ld build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ABC.app/ABC normal x86_64
>   [ERROR] :  (1 failure)

I tried to rebuild the module on my own for [this](https://github.com/hansemannn/titanium-google-signin/releases) source code and added the module in my app, still same issue exist.

Below is my configuration:
Mac OS : **Mac OS X (10.13.3)**
Node.js Version : **8.9.1**
npm Version : **5.5.1**
CLI Version : **5.1.1**
SDK Version : **7.2.0.GA**
Xcode : **9.4.1**
Gplus Module Source Code version: **1.4.0**

I will be very thankful if you let me know, what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Try to increment the min ios versión on your tiapp.xml file to at least iOS 9: <min-ios-ver>9.0</min-ios-ver> I solved the same issue with that. I hope it helps.